# How to display my JSON String value in android?

Tags: android, json

I have the following code to display my JSON String value in the android code.

```
        try
        {
                 String json="[{"new_status":{"uname1":"sibin1","pass1":"shanu1","upid1":141,"uname2":"sibin2","pass2":"shanu2","upid2":142,"uname3":"sibin3","pass3":"shanu3","upid3":143}}]";
                 JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
                 String abc1=null;
                 String abc2=null;

                 String uname=null;
                 String pass=null;
                 String upid=null;               

                 int i2=0;
                 for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                 {
                     JSONObject e = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                     JSONObject jsonObject = e.getJSONObject("new_status");
                     text.setText(text.getText().toString()+String.valueOf("Total Array Length: "+jsonObject.length()+"\n"));        
                     String [] nm=new String[jsonObject.length()];
                     String [] pa=new String[jsonObject.length()];
                     String [] up=new String[jsonObject.length()];                       

                     for(int i1=0;i1<jsonObject.length();i1++)
                     {
                         i2=i1+1;
                         nm[i1]="uname"+i2;
                         pa[i1]="pass"+i2;
                         up[i1]="upid"+i2;                       
                     }   

                      for(int i3=0;i3<nm.length;i3++)
                      {  
                           text.setText(text.getText().toString()+String.valueOf(jsonObject.getString(nm[i3]+" "+pa[i3]+" "+up[i3]+"\n")));
                      }
                 }                    
            } 
            catch (JSONException e) 
            {
                text.setText("JSON Exception Occurs ");
            }
```

I am getting JSON Exception error. where my JSON String is completely valid , i tested in jsonlint website.  i don't know why i am getting the JSON Exception error.

Please suggest me solution.

Comment: Log the exception (`e.printStackTrace()` or `Log.e("JSON","JSONError",e)`), and please include the stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a number of things that could be causing this error. To debug them, you need the full stack trace.

```
        catch (JSONException e) 
        {
            Log.e("json","JSONException",e);
        }
```

When you include that, it will automatically include the JSON text, and show you which line is causing your JSONException.

For my guess, I imagine you aren't reading it right. JSON is very finicky when it comes to the order of items.

Comment: Yes thanks i got the error , i was doing array indexing error. I have given wrong array size to three array nm , pa , up . the array size should be 3 and loop also continues for 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
import android.util.Log;

Log.d("json",String.valueOf(jsonObject));
```

Comment: in the try and catch structure

Comment: import add it to the beginning of the code along with other imports